# Ampersands in database

Tags: php, xml, html-entities, ampersand, addslashes

I am trying to write a php function that goes to my database and pulls a list of URLS and arranges them into an xml structure and creates an xml file.

Problem is, Some of these urls will contain an ampersand that ARE HTML encoded. So, the database is good, but currently, when my function tries to grab these URLS, the script will stop at the ampersands and not finish.

One example link from database:

```
http://www.mysite.com/myfile.php?select=on&amp;league_id=8&amp;sport=15
```

```php
function buildXML($con) {
//build xml file
$sql = "SELECT * FROM url_links";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con);

$gameArray = array ();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    array_push($row['form_link']);
    }

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><channel>';

foreach ($gameArray as $link)
    {   
        $xml .= "<item><link>".$link."</link></item>";  
    }

$xml .= '</channel>';   
file_put_contents('../xml/full_rankings.xml',$xml);
}

mysql_close($con);
session_write_close();
```

If i need to alter the links in the database, that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) on the `$link` to convert `&amp;` back to `&`.

In your XML, you could also wrap the link in `<![CDATA[]]>` to allow it to contain the characters.

```
$xml .= "<item><link><![CDATA[" . html_entity_decode($link) . "]]></link></item>";
```

**UPDATE**
Just noticed you're actually not putting anything into the `$gameArray`:

```
array_push($row['form_link']);
```

Try:

```
$gameArray[] = $row['form_link'];
```

* @Musa looks to have noticed it first, for due credit.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line

```
array_push($row['form_link']);
```

you never put anything in the `$gameArray` array, it should be

```
array_push($gameArray, $row['form_link']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). It will decode any encoded special characters in string passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely what you are looking for:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Read the documentation, there are examples at the bottom of the page...

'&' in oracleSQL and MySQL are used in queries as a logical operator which is why it is tossing an error.

You may also want to decode the HTML...

Comment: The OP says nothing about MySQL errors and even "*the database is good*"; the problem/question is regarding outputting the data in XML.